# Inserting characters into specified fields in large files

Tags: awk, sed

Here is my question. I have several hundred files that are too large to edit utilizing vi editor. I'm looking for a possible awk or sed command to manipulate my files.  Bit of a rookie. I have a simplified file:

```
001|1|3|053412|16|1234|||
001|21|4|123618|15|88|||
```

The files were created, with the fourth field being in the wrong format.
The fourth field should be 05:34:12  reflecting HH:MM:SS. The time values are correct, I just need to insert the `:` in the appropriate places.

How do I insert the colons after the second character and the fourth characters in the fourth field? I cannot do it by character count since the values before and after the fourth field are variable.

Comment: are fields always separated by one or more vertical bars?, 
Is the number of fields always the same ?

Comment: yes the delimiter is pipes. I have my answer, thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

`gawk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '{$4=gensub(/(..)(..)(..)/,"\\1:\\2:\\3","g",$4)}1' file

001|1|3|05:34:12|16|1234|||
001|21|4|12:36:18|15|88|||
```

otherwise you can do the same with `substr($4,1,2)":"...`

Comment: Karakfa... I bow down to you!!! You are my HERO!!! Thank you SO VERY MUCH.. You are a GOD!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub() and inplace editing

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$4=gensub(/(..)(..)/,"\\1:\\2:",1,$4)} 1' *
```

Similarly with GNU sed for EREs and inplace editing:

```
sed -i -E 's/(([^|]*\|){3}..)(..)/\1:\3:/' *
```

e.g.:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$4=gensub(/(..)(..)/,"\\1:\\2:",1,$4)} 1' file
001|1|3|05:34:12|16|1234|||
001|21|4|12:36:18|15|88|||

$ sed -E 's/(([^|]*\|){3}..)(..)/\1:\3:/' file
001|1|3|05:34:12|16|1234|||
001|21|4|12:36:18|15|88|||
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|)([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1\2:\3:\4/' file
001|1|3|05:34:12|16|1234|||
001|21|4|12:36:18|15|88|||
```

Comment: Appreciate it Kenavoz!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk!

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{r=split($4,T,"");for(i=2;i<=r;i+=2){if(i!=r)T[i]=T[i]":"}tmp="";for(i=1;i<=r;i++){tmp=tmp T[i]}$4=tmp;}1' file

001|1|3|05:34:12|16|1234|||
001|21|4|12:36:18|15|88|||
```

Longer whit explanation:

```
BEGIN{
FS=OFS="|"; #Field separator and output field separator
}
{
    tmp="";
    r=split($4,time_field,""); # Chunk field into pieces
    for(i=2;i<=r;i+=2) # Loop two by two
    {
        if(i!=r)
        {
            time_field[i]=time_field[i]":"; # Add ":"
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=r;i++) # Loop over again to rebuild
    {
        tmp=tmp time_field[i];
    }
    $4=tmp; #rebuid field
    print
}

How you could use it in bash: Save it as whatever.awk

while IFS='' read -r file
do
awk -f whatever.awk "$file" > out_file
done < list_of_files_to_edit.txt
```

If you want edit the files in place, you can add the option -i to Kenavoz sed command. sed -ri ...

Comment: You should mention that only works in awks that split strings into individual characters given a null field separator (GNU awk will but it's undefined behavior in POSIX). When writing shell loops always use `IFS=` and `-r` unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not doing so and full understand the side effects (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). You have awk syntax issues - read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins

Comment: @EdMorton I can not see sintax issues, can you give me an example?

Comment: The first arg to sub() is a regexp, not a string, so you should be using `sub(/:$/,"",tmp)`, not `sub(":$","",tmp)`. The trailing semicolons are just cluttering up the code. `print $0` should just be `print`. Your loops add `:`s then have to remove the last one instead of only adding just what you want and why add to the array elements and then build a string from them instead of just doing it in one loop. Oh, and aside from the awk stuff you have to quote all your shell variables - use `"$file"`, not `$file`.

Comment: @EdMorton Now looks better, I think

Comment: Yeah but I still don't understand why you have 2 loops instead of just one like `for (i=1;i<=r;i++) tmp = tmp time_field[i] (i%2 || i==r ? "" : ":")` or similar. There's just no need to modify the array first and THEN populate tmp. You've still got all those traililing semi-colons at the end of most, but not all, lines cluttering it up too.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(([^|]*\|){3})(..)(..)/\1\3:\4:/' file
```

Use back references to group the first three fields and the following two pairs. Then format the 4th field as required.